# $http.get breaks AngularJS variables from response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to cache a html file containing some angular variables, but when I append the file contents to dom, all the variables are just plain text like `{{ variable.name.here }}`

I'm retrieving the html file with $http.get like this:

```
$http.get('app/shared/partials/raise-error.html').then(function(res){
    $templateCache.put('raiseErrorBlock', res.data);
});
```

...and this is the raise-error.html (part of it):

```
<div id="raiseError" ng-show="errorParams.raise" class="slide-down">
    <div class="raiseErrorWrapper">
        <div class="rew-header">
            <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
            <span class="rewh-title">{{ errorParams.title }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm running the $http.get inside run() block for any matter.

EDIT: from what i can see it's a templateCache issue. Does templateCache have support for variables or it can only cache static data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$compile` service to make angular expressions work properly.

```
var $el = $compile('<div>{{myData}}</div>')(scope);
$body.append($el); // wrapped $body with jqLite
```

As *ngdoc* says:

> $compile - Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces
>   a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the
>   template together.

You can also use shorter method of storing something in $templateCache eg.

```
$http.get('http://myserver.com/file.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
}).then(function(response) {
  // do sth
});
```

I also created plnkr for you. Hope it will help you.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ls4kllAvdVb3qMvm3mBA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it works! I see that if I wanna use this inside a service, i have to replace (scope) with ($rootScope.$new())

Comment: It's not exactly as you said because if you use the same code in eg. controller, you have to use $compile too. Just to clarify, you have to inject a scope to template function (returned by $compile service) if you want manually insert something to the DOM.

Comment: Indeed, you have to use $compile, but I was saying that in a service you cannot inject $scope, but you can inject $rootScope, so you'll have to make something like this ``var scope = $rootScope.$new();`` so that ``$compile(html)(scope)`` will work.